# ReplacingCharactersInRange out of bounds error

Tags: ios, objective-c, indexoutofboundsexception, invalidargumentexception

I have a textfield that accepts numbers and I am trying to replace the 8th character in the string with a "."

```
if(self.txtQty.text.length >= 8){
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(8,1);
    self.txtQty.text = [self.txtQty.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"."];
}
```

-Example-
1234567.90

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or index out of bounds'
> *** First throw call stack:

I keep receiving this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range `{8,1}` means you are trying to access the 9th character. But your `if` check only verifies if the string has 8 or more characters. So if the string is exactly 8 characters long then you will get that error.

Update your `if` check to:

```
if (self.txtQty.text.length > 8) {
```

Or possibly your `if` check is correct and the range should be changed from `{8,1}`, to `{7,1}` to replace the 8th character.

Which of those two changes you make depends on your goal (to change the 8th or 9th character).

---

To help visualize the range, I'll attempt a bit of a drawing:

Some string, its indexes, and range `{8,1}`:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0   <-- The string
| | | | | | | | | | |
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1  <-- Its indexes
                    0
                ***    <-- Area for {8,1}
```

Here you can see that the range `{8,1}` is getting the 9th character.

Comment: Thank you very much, I left my if check the same and adjusted the range to {7,1} it works now.